# How to add a class in another one or an alternative

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello I explain my problem I have a list of patients with their coordinates all that is registered in a class by clicking on one of the patient a life opens with the information of the patient in question.

I want to add the possibility to add notes (an unlimited number of notes per patient) so I need another list but I do not know how to link the two

I would like that when I click on a patient it loads the information of this patient from the list of notes

***Here is the list of my patients***

```
class Patients {
  final String name;

  final String firstname;
  final String dateofbirth;
  final String email;
  final String numero;
  final String id;
  final DateTime date;

  Patients(
      {required this.name,
      required this.firstname,
      required this.dateofbirth,
      required this.email,
      required this.numero,
      required this.id,
      required this.date});
}
```

***Here is the list of patient notes***

```
class ListNote {
  final String? title;
  final String? note;
  final String? conclusion;

  ListNote({
    this.title,
    this.note,
    this.conclusion,
  });
}
```

[My patient screen list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIprI.png)

In the red frame is the information of my first list of patients.

In the blue boxes you will find the notes linked to the patient

[Patient page with more info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8DGz.png)

**Thank you for your help**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I got from your point is you want to add List of Notes in Patient class. If that's the case you can simply add that in Patient class like this:

```
class Patients {
  final String name;
  final List<ListNote> listOfNotes;
  final String firstname;
  final String dateofbirth;
  final String email;
  final String numero;
  final String id;
  final DateTime date;

  Patients({
      required this.name,
      required this.listOfNotes,
      required this.firstname,
      required this.dateofbirth,
      required this.email,
      required this.numero,
      required this.id,
      required this.date
  });
}


class ListNote {
  final String? title;
  final String? note;
  final String? conclusion;

  ListNote({
    this.title,
    this.note,
    this.conclusion,
  });
}
```

Comment: Yes I think it must be that however I don't know how to implement it in one of my list and how to read this list can you help me? 
I explain it in the answer below

Comment: Yes I can. That would be easy like if you want to call that list then it would be like

```late Patient patient;
patient = //assign patient object
List<ListNote> notes = patient.listofNotes;
```